# as.Date function doesn't work. The output is either "NA" or the year is 2020

Tags: r

I have a string variable. I want to convert it to a Date variable.
I used `as.Date` but the output is not correct.

I tried `format = "%d%b%Y"`. However it didn't work. The new dates don't make sense to me. for "06MAR2007" I have 2020-03-06. It seems all the days and months are correct. However, I have 2020 for all the years.

I also tried `format = %b%d%Y`. However, the output is "NA".

The output of `(x <- 0; class(x) <- "Date"; x)` is 1970-01-01. I even tried to change the origin but still the code didn't work.

```
a$arrivaldate <- as.Date(a$arrivaldate, format="%d%b%y", origin = "1900-01-01")
```

Comment: `as.Date('06MAR2007', '%d%b%Y')` gives me `"2007-03-06"`, are you not seeing that?

Comment: Which package is `as.date` from?

Comment: If you used `as.Date` as in the subject and not `as.date` as in the question then it might be that your language is set to one for which MAR does not correspond to a valid month.  What is `Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")` ?  If it is something that would not have MAR as valid then change it:  `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")`

Comment: I used "as.Date" and I think it is from base R.

Comment: @ G.Grothendieck: I got an error. could not find function "Sys.getlocate".

Comment: @ Robert: that code gives me "2020-03-06".

Comment: @Mahsa Its "Sys.getloca**l**e" not "Sys.getloca**t**e". Cut and paste to avoid typing errors.

Comment: @ G.Grothendieck: sorry, I don't have internet connection on the UNIX system that i am working with. That's why I couldn't copy and paste. The output is : "en_CA.ISO8859-1"

Comment: Just do `Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "C")` that usually solves 99% of these type of problems

Comment: I tried `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_CA.ISO8859-1"); as.Date("06MAR2007", "%d%b%Y")` on a Linux box, but I got the right answer, so something very fishy is going on.  Please add the output from `sessionInfo()` and `getOption("encoding")` to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what is the root cause, but this error will be resolved by changing the date format of the year input.

Example in your case:

```
date <- '06MAR2007' 
day <- substr(date, 1, 2)  # Returns 06
month <- substr(date, 3, 5) # Returns MAR
year <- substr(date, 8, 9) #Returns 07

as.Date(paste(day, month, year, sep=''), format = "%d%b%y") # Returns 2007-03-06
format(as.Date(paste(day, month, year, sep=''), format = "%d%b%y"), "%d%m%Y") # Returns 06032007
```

The downside is, this method will not work for earlier periods e.g. Year 1968 and before.  If your input date is 1968, it will return 2068.